# jQuery Scrollto on dynamic menu/page sections

Tags: jquery, html, scrollto

I am creating a single page word-press theme. I have a menu that is dynamically populated whenever a new page is created, for each menu item, a section is added to my page. When you click the menu item, the page scrolls down to the section.

Each section has a class "section" and the unique ID of the page name. Likewise, each menu item has a class "menu_item" and ID of the page name.

I'm struggling to code the right jQuery to make the page scroll to the section (currently it just jumps).

**jQuery:**

```
var $paneTarget = $("body");
var $section_name = $('.section').attr('data-slug');
var $menu_link = $('.menu_item').attr('data-slug');

$('$menu_link').click(function(){
    $paneTarget.scrollTo('$section_name', 800);
    return false;
});
```

**And the outputted html for my menu:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="menu_item about" data-slug="about" href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu_item portfolio" data-slug="portfolio" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu_item services" data-slug="services" href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu_item test-page" data-slug="test-page" href="#test-page">Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu_item home" data-slug="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>        
</ul>
```

**Lastly, the outputted html for my sections**

```
<section class="section" id="about" data-slug="about"  ><h1></section>
<section class="section" id="portfolio" data-slug="portfolio"  ><h1></section>
<section class="section" id="services" data-slug="services"  ><h1></section>
<section class="section" id="test-page" data-slug="test-page"  ><h1></section>
<section class="section" id="home" data-slug="home"  ><h1></section>
```

The issue I'm having is with jQuery, getting the page to `scrollTo` each section when I press a menu item. Bearing in mind that all menu items and pages are created dynamically, so I need to code it so it covers new pages being added.

Comment: use `.on()` instead of `.click()` to handle delegated events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is that your jQuery code never gets called. see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/39sC5/1/) as you can see on click it should `alert "here"` but it never will. `return false`gets called to late and better is to use `preventDefault()`.

try like this:

```
$('.menu_item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-slug');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39sC5/

depending on which jQuery version you are using you can change `$('.menu_item').click(function(e)...` to `$('.menu_item').on('click', function(e)...`